# How should I manage dependencies among test cases

Tags: java, unit-testing, go, testng

I wonder whether it is possible to ensure the execution order of test cases in Go.

For example in Java, this can be achieved with TestNG's `dependsOnMethods` (or `dependsOnGroups` alike) attribute within the `@Test` annotation as below:

```java
@Test
public void serverStartedOk() {}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "serverStartedOk" })
public void method1() {}
```

With this, `method1` would be executed after `serverStartedOk`. Any approach to achieve this with Go?

Comment: No, this is not supported in Go. In fact, it's bad practice to depend on execution order, regardless of your language. But Go makes it easy to run only a subset of tests with the `-run=` flag, which would render any ordering meaningless.

Comment: If your goal is simply to make sure that a server is running, or some other dependent state, do that outside of the testing framework.